# How to update CollectionViewSource's Source property from Task?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, .net-4.0

I want to load my `CollectionViewSource` asynchronously. So I wrote such code:

```
list1 = new List<int>();
list2 = new List<int>();

Task.Factory.StartNew<Tuple<List<int>, List<int>>>(() =>
{
    // Create and return tuple with 2 lists
}).ContinueWith(doneTask =>
{
    list1 = doneTask.Result.Item1;
    list2 = doneTask.Result.Item2;
    // update UI
    collectionViewSource1.Source = list1;
    collectionViewSource2.Source = list2;
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

But this code doesn't work.

Exception `System.ArgumentException: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.` occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DependencyObjects have thread affinity, you cannot modify them on a background thread. You should be able to do this using the application's Dispatcher like this:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
    collectionViewSource1.Source = list1;
    collectionViewSource2.Source = list2;
}, null);
```

This [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) might provide more relevant information.

Comment: @H.B.: This code doesn't work too. It raises the same exception.

Comment: @H.B.: My debugger doesn't show line of code when exception occurs, but if I comment these 2 lines: collectionViewSource1.Source = list1; collectionViewSource2.Source = list2, the code works fine. I could even update UI, but couldn't update this binding.

Comment: Could it be that the CollectionViewSources have not been created on the UI thread either?

Comment: "TPL"? I have tried to do something similar and if the CollectionViewSource is created on the UI-Thread it throws an exception if accessed in another thread i created. If i use `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` however it works for me as expected...